# why I can't leave class blank

Tags: python, class

When I delete the ' pass'  command and leave the class blank, it show error :

```
File "class_distance.py", line 6
    point1=distance()   
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

The code is expected to calculate distance between two points. 
Here is code:

```
import math 
class distance(object):
     pass


point1=distance()   
point2=distance()
point1.x=input("x=")
point2.x=input("x=")
point1.y=input("y=")
point2.y=input("y=")


def main(point1,point2):


    dx = point1.x - point2.x
    dy = point1.y - point2.y
    dist = math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
    print dist

main(point1,point2)
```

Comment: I know this is very simple but I could not find any satisfactory answer. I'm new at programming

Answer (score 4):

When you end a line with the colon, you're declaring a compound statement: Python expects a block of code following that statement. The `pass` keyword is your way of saying that you don't want to enter the block yet.

Because of the way whitespace is significant in Python, not allowing an empty statement makes the code more readable and easier to parse: after the colon, an indented block is expected and if there's none, it's an error, end of story.

**EDIT**: By the way, if you're wondering, you get an `IndentationError` on the next statement, rather than on the `class` declaration, because Python thinks that is the body of the class declaration, and expects it to be properly indented.

Answer (score 2):

It's because Python is expecting the class body after it sees

```
class distance(object):
```

In particular that colon signals we're going to indent the next line and type the class's body. However if we don't indent and we just continue on programming, Python will become upset and complain that we've skipped the class body.

In order to allow empty blocks, there is a keyword `pass` which basically acts as a placeholder for where the class or function or whatever would normally go.

```
class distance(object):
    pass # Let's python know we didn't forget the class body
keep.on.programming()
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes must have a body. So when you delete pass it searches the next statement as body, but as it is on the same level as your class definition, Python says there's an IndentationError.

Answer (score 0):

A code block in python must contain *some* code so if you don't want to make it do anything, you have to put in `pass`. Hence the `IndentationError`